# RegEx replace all values of width and height in HTML-tags

Tags: php, html, regex, dom

I got this RegEx from another post, but it doesn't fully function like it should.

Here is the pattern: `/(<[^>]+ (height|width)=)"[^"]*"/gi` and replacement: `$1"auto"`

Here is a typical replacement string:
`<p width="123" height="345"></p>`

Now, I would like this to return `<p width="auto" height="auto"></p>`, but instead it returns `<p width="123" height="auto"></p>`.

Could you help me figure out how you can replace both the width and height-values in an HTML-tag? Oh, and I would really like it to work with small apostroph-signs as well (e.g. `width='*'`).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Generally, yes it is trouble - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags for a great discussion on the subject. (X)HTML is just too complex to be parsed by regex.

Comment: @andyb: Somewhat worthless discussion since it has little relation to OPs case; and because second only few people read past the jokes and through the actual technical explanations. (Btw, modern regex implementations can match nested structures / recursively. Which again, is not relevant here.)

Comment: @mario I'm answering @Emil's comment about whether RegEx + HTML = trouble. Also, what makes you think the OP will not read all the comments? But I take your point that it's not really relevant for the original question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't do this with regex. Use the DOM instead -- it's not very hard:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($yourHTML);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$widthelements = $xpath->query('//*[@width]'); // get any elements with a width attribute

foreach ($widthelements as $el) {
    $el->setAttribute('width', 'auto');
}

$heightelements = $xpath->query('//*[@height]'); // get any elements with a height attribute
foreach ($heightelements as $el) {
    $el->setAttribute('height', 'auto');
}

$yourHTML = $dom->saveHTML();
```

It might be better simply to remove the attribute instead -- if so, do `$el->removeAttribute('width');` or the analogous operation on `height`.

Comment: Thank you. How is the speed of this compared to RegEx, though?

Comment: @Emil perfectly fine, especially when you consider the relative costs of developer time and CPU time.

Comment: @Emil: have you shown that this portion of your application is a performance hotspot?

Comment: Speed of execution, probably several degrees slower. Actual effectiveness, considerably higher. Speed of development, even more times higher. Unless the DOM work is a significant drain on performance (which is unlikely) and unless you can get a regex to do exactly the same job (even more unlikely), go for the DOM approach.

Comment: @Michael: No, not really, it's just that it might be parsing large amounts of data at a time.

Comment: Argh, this DOM is messing up my encoding.. How can you set the input HTML to UTF-8 encoding..?

Comment: @Emil I think you need to put `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` into your `head`.

Answer (score 3):

Please use [an HTML parser](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) and not a regular expression. Please?

```
$input = '<p width="123" height="345"></p>';
$doc = DOMDocument->loadHTML($input);

// ... make changes ...

$output = $doc->saveHTML();
```